# Do 'Locals' and 'Police' NPCs in the cities respawn?

Tags: 7.62-high-calibre

Do the generic NPCs in towns respawn? If yes - how long does it take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about most important npcs, but im sure soldiers/police respawn and i think the civilians might respawn. The soldiersrespawn when a convoy (red, green or other-colored arrow) passes through or stops at the city.